# react jest test without assertions to test rendering with getBy queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

`@testing-library/react` provides several methods for querying rendered elements including `getBy*` queries which will throw an error if the element is not found.

How should I handle this in my test when I just want to test that there rendered elements are on screen.
When the `getBy` throws an error if element is not found there is no need to assert that `expect(element).toBeInTheDocument()` but then I have a test without assertion.

Should I use a dummy assertion like `expect(1).toBe(1)` or whats the best practice here?

Example:

```js
describe("MyComponent", () => {

  // Render helper
  function renderer(props) {
    const result = render(<MyComponent {...props} />);

    // Will throw error when element with text "My element" is not found
    const element = screen.getByText("My element");

    return {...result, element);
  }

  it("renders with my element", () => {
    const {element} = renderer({});
   
    // Redundant, will always pass when reaching this point
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  // Has same effect but does not use assertion
  it("renders with my element w/o assertion", () => {
    renderer({});

    // expect(1).toBe(1); // When using dummy assertion jest wont complain
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: It's not clear to me if you're asking for people's opinions on "the best way" to do this-- [opinion-based questions are considered off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions).

Having said that, if all you're trying to test is that your render call succeeded, then you can assert that it didn't throw an exception, like so:

```
it("renders without errors", () => {
    expect(() => renderer({})).not.toThrow();
});
```

If that's not what you're asking, maybe you can clarify the language in your question a bit.